# Emails go to the spam folder

Tags: smtp, hosting, cpanel

I recently bought a reseller server and when I went to setup the emails of one of the cpanel accounts, I tried to send a test to my Gmail but it always arrives in the spam folder, I don't know why, because SPF is PASS and DKIM too and the current server isn't on a blacklist. I leave the mail header:

```
https://pastebin[.]com/bbszLNKe
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the tour https://stackoverflow.com/tour and make sure to input all the code you've tried in your question (*not* as an image) and tell exactly what you expected to achieve with the code and what went not as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gastronomiaamazonica.pe is listed in SpamHaus DBL

https://www.spamhaus.org/query/domain/gastronomiaamazonica.pe

Your server doesn't have proper reverse->forward DNS entries.

104.218.55.84 resolves to server1.gastronomiaamazonica.pe.

But server1.gastronomiaamazonica.pe does not resolve back to 104.218.55.84 (or anything for that matter).